Group representation determined up to isomorphism by image of homomorphism in $GL(V)$?
Consider a group representation homomorphism $\rho: G\rightarrow H\subset GL(V)$. Let $q$ an isomorphism from $H$ to $H'\subset GL(V)$, does the composition $q\circ \rho$ give a representation that is isomorphic to $\rho$? In other words, if $V$ is a representation of the group $G$, can we determine the representation up to isomorphism if we know the isomorphism class of the image $\rho(G)$?
(I came up with this question myself)

What do you think? Have you tried any examples?

This is not true. The problem is that the group structure of the image does not tell you how it acts on the vector space.
As a counterexample, consider two 1-dimensional representations $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}^\times$, one given by mapping the generator $1$ to $i$, the other mapping $1$ to $-i$. Both have image isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, but the representations are not isomorphic.
As a sidenote, there's a difference between your two phrasings of your question. Given representations $\varphi, \psi \colon G \to \text{GL}(V)$, there's a difference between:

There exists an isomorphism $\varphi(G) \cong \psi(G)$.
There exists an isomorphism $q : \varphi(G) \to \psi(G)$ such that $q \circ \varphi = \psi$.


In your counterexample the two representations are still related by an automorphism of $G$. It is possible to give more extreme examples where this doesn't happen, e.g. there is such an example for $G = C_2$ using diagonal matrices of order $2$ with different numbers of $-1$ eigenvalues.
